# Ordering the terms of a differential equation, individual output form

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to change the output format of a second order differential equation. Mathematica puts the `x[t]` terms and its derivatives in an ascending order like

`m*g*h == x[t] + x'[t] + x''[t]`

how can I reverse it and get the following output?

`x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == m*g*h`

Comment: You might use this: `expr = HoldForm[x''[t] + x'[t] + x[t] == m g h]`. This gives exactly what you want. This is, however, only the form to look at, but one cannot further operate with this expression. To be able to operate further, one needs to unblock it: `ReleaseHold[expr]`.

Comment: The equation above is only an example, I am searching for a dynamic solution like `MyOutput = OrderFormat[MyInputDiffEquation, ascending]`

Comment: This is a question that has been many times discussed that Mma has its own internal format. One cannot influence it while he wants to keep his expressions available to further calculations. No way around. However, after the calculations are finished, or on the intermediate step one can want to have a comfortable look at the expression. Then there are two ways. One I have shown you. The other has been proposed by David Park in his package "Presentation Master". But then you need to have this package.